# Angular js material date picker open on focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

When I focus md-datepicker-input, I need to open date picker not only dropdown down icon click. Also I need a place holder custom text, where its initially showing current date. [Reference](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker)

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" formate="DD-MM-YYYY" md-min-date="minDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can refer below issue raised on material source.
https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4650

Answer (score 0):

you need to add md-open-on-focus 
`<md-datepicker md-open-on-focus ng-model="myDate" formate="DD-MM-YYYY" md-min-date="minDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>`